# How can I display an OpenCV IplImage in Gtk+/Gtkmm?

Tags: image-processing, gtk, opencv, gtkmm

I've got images as IplImage that I want to display in a small Gtkmm application. How can I convert them to something Gtk can display?

Comment: Since you solved it yourself, it's probably best to copy the solution into an answer post, and then select that answer as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new pixbuf using **`gdk_new_pixbuf_from_data()`** passing it the image format parameters corresponding to the format of the IplImage.  The IplImage image data is accessed via the **`imageData`** field.

Here is some [example code](http://www.gtkforums.com/about2583.html) from a Gtk forum.

Answer (score 3):

Posting OP's solution as answer:

```
IplImage* image;
cvCvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2RGB);
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> pixbuf = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data(
        (guint8*)image->imageData,
        Gdk::COLORSPACE_RGB,
        false,
        image->depth,
        image->width,
        image->height,
        image->widthStep);

Gtk::Image gtk_img;
gtk_img.set(pixbuf);
```